# How to call script while pressing plus icon in bootstrap responsive table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 with JSF primefaces.In my page I using bootstrap responsive table.In mobile view a plus icon appears in the first column.Now the requirement is to call a script while pressing the plus icon.

```
<table id="table" style="width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>....</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I used mozilla firebug to get below code

```
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<td style="width:35%" tabindex="0">
::before
</td>
</tr>
```

**dataTable.css**

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr[role="row"] > 
td:first-child::before, table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed > tbody > tr[role="row"] > th:first-child::before {
    top: 9px;
    left: 4px;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #444;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: 0 !important;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    line-height: 14px;
    content: '+';
    background-color: #31b131;
}
```

I need content + icon press to call script

[Responsive table with plus icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx1Ht.png)

Comment: I think you need to describe your problem better. It's hard to understand.

Comment: My brain hurts after trying to understand that question

Comment: @ThanveerShah now modify to given image link

Comment: Give an onclick event on the press icon

Comment: Its bootstrap create plus icon in mobile view .Then how to given onclick event?

Comment: Its fine, you can still use an onclick event, It would be great if you could post the entire code in jsFiddle or codepen